# wamp server local project folder not accessing

Tags: php, zend-framework, wampserver

My wamp server working but home page Your projects folder click not working

But working for this type called in address bar **localhost/emp**  emp was local project folder name

I want direct clicking to be work

Any one say how to configure correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend Framework or any Framework for Projects, you have to make sure the Routing / Bootstrap working properly. Make sure that your apache is configured to allow URL rewriting . Edit the **httpd.conf** and enable the mod_rewrite module. Then restart the server and try access your website .

Comment: how to enable this module. If u don t mine i am in new for php.

Comment: I have enable but now also click that folder now accessing

Comment: Httpd.conf file is present in the Apache installed directory . You can search for this file in the windows explorer after going to the Apache Installed Directory. For example if you installed Wamp in C:/Wamp, you can see the httpd.conf file in C:\Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf  depending on the version of your wamp . Now you have to edit the httpd.conf file and find the line #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so . Remove the # in front of the line and save . Now restart your server.  If this doesn't work, please share details of the framework, application you are using !

Comment: Please elaborate your  real problem, software/framework you are using, etc.

Comment: i have enable the service module and restart. But its same problem

no softwares now only installed. just update version install thats it.

Comment: Okay, there some issue understanding your exact issue . Please elaborate the issue .

Answer (score 0):

So simple for this answer

C:\wamp\www

In index.php 
line 338

($suppress_localhost ? 'http://' : '')

change http://   to http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

On Wamp 3.1.9

Access your `www` folder on Wamp, then edit index.php (it's the default index page included with Wamp)

Search on the index page for `$suppress` by clicking `ctrl + F` command you will find

```
$suppress_localhost = ($wampConf['urlAddLocalhost'] == 'off' ? true : false);
```

now change true to false and false to true,

```
$suppress_localhost = ($wampConf['urlAddLocalhost'] == 'off' ? false : true);
```

Now save and restart your Wamp server then click on your project and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the my.ini file located at "\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17". Note the 5.6.17 may differ based on your version.
2. Find the line that says [mysqld].
3. Add this code after this line: bind-address = [server_ip]
4. Replace [server_ip] with the static IP address of your server.
5. Open config.inc.php located at "\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14". Note the 4.1.14 may differ based on your version.
6. Locate the following code: $cfg[‘Servers’][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'
7. Change the 127.0.0.1 to the static IP address of your server.
8. Configure your firewall to allow connection through the default Apache and MySQL ports.
9. Open the control panel on the server computer
   Select System and Security –> Windows Firewall –> Advanced Settings
   In the left pane, select “Inbound Rules” and then choose “New Rule…” on the right pane.
   Select “Port” and click “Next”
   Select “TCP” and enter the default ports for Apache and MySQL (80, 3306) in the text box next to "Specific local ports:" Note: be sure to change these if you changed them in your wampserver (i.e. my.ini).
   Choose “Allow the Connection” and click “Next”
   Check all the domains you want to allow these ports (i.e Domain, Private, Public)
   Specify a name for this rule and click “finish”
   Restart all services and now you should be able to connect to your database.